Backup VPN connection from Teltonika router
I have a problem with setting up a backup VPN connection from my Teltonika router.
Some background first, I have two servers on different locations. One of them is my main server and the other one is the backup server for when the main server is down or unavailable. I am using multible types of Teltonika routers like the RUT360 and RUT956. I have them set up with a VPN connection to my main server (PPTP), which is working for a while without any problems/complains.
But now I want to make them like when they can't connect with my main server VPN they should automatically try to connect to the backup server VPN. But when I setup both connection the router make conncetion to both the servers at the same time.


For obvious reasons I changed the IP addresses in the screenshots.
What I found out is that I can access the routers by Teltonika's RMS service and switching the VPN connection manually, but this isn't a real solution for me.
Is this even possible with Teltonika routers that I use/got, or do I need other types? And if so how could I set this up?

I don’t think you’ll be able to change how the router uses its primary and backup VPN. It doesn’t sound like it’s setup to automatically switch over but be connected to both in the event it requires to fail over. Honestly failover servers are typically this way anyway
